# Reference Request: Vector-Valued Ito Formula

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, hilbert-spaces, stochastic-differential-equations

I know that there exist Ito formulae to understand
$
f(X),
$
where $f: H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is sufficiently nice, $H$ is a Hilbert space and $X$ is an $H$-valued semi-martingale.

However I'm wondering if there is a generalization or analogue for $f: H \mapsto \tilde{H}$, sufficiently nice operators between Hilbert spaces?  I haven't been able to find anything, any references in the right direction are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Curtain and Falb (1970)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82209342.pdf) treated this case.